# Non-standardized vs Standardized Data Normality

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, standardization, central-limit-theorem

[image][image] I have a dataset with over 900 cases.  I performed a Q-Q Plot on the non-standardized HRV data (dependent variable), and the points formed a wavy curve indicating it does not follow a normal distribution.  The accompanying histogram is right-tailed, and the box plot shows several outliers.  The study design is repeated measures (within-subjects), where each subject is exposed to 13 scenes (treatments).  I first standardized each subject's 13 responses within the subject (13 HRV scores standardized), and then grouped each subject's standardized results with 73 total subjects (73 x 13 = 949 data points).  This resulted in data with a MEAN = 0, but STD = 0.96.  I then "re-standardized" this data, which resulted in MEAN = 0 and STD = 1.  The resulting Q-Q Plot is now a straight line with a few stragglers on the ends, the histogram is symmetrical, and the box plot shows only one near outlier.  Furthermore, the Shapiro-Wilk normality hypothesis test no longer rejects the null hypothesis of the distribution of the population as normal.  I realize as a dependent variable a normal distribution is unnecessary, but I would like to standardize to facilitate comparison with other physiological and psychological dependent variables I also have in the study.  The questions:  Is this a valid way to standardize DV values such that each participant's individual heart physiologies (some more consistently higher values, some more consistently lower values) are accounted for equally within the 73-participant group (such that no one individual's scores have more influence than another individual), and could the resulting normal distribution be a valid result?  Two other alternatives suggested in feedback include 1) Adding a control for physiology, or 2) Using a Multilevel model, which I think would mean the Individual 13 responses = LEVEL 1, and the entire group of 73 participants together (949 responses) = LEVEL 2?

Comment: I have added the BEFORE (non-standardized) and AFTER (standardized) results above. Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: I am using Analyse-It software within the Excel environment.

Comment: The formula used to standardize is as you say below:  (value - MEAN) / STDEV.

Comment: I will be fitting to a series of linear multiple regression models with several IVs, and also comparing results with several other DVs.  I would like to meet the assumptions of GLMs as much as possible.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Mark. Whatever you did is not what is usually undertood as "standardizing" and it certainly is not just the recentering and rescaling you imply.  It *looks* like the entire distribution might have been transformed to make it approximately Normal, but I cannot see any information concerning what was actually done.  // What is a "DV dataset"??  // Why are you concerned about the distribution in the first place?

Comment: A series of participants experienced 13 virtual reality scenes presented in a random order.  I first standardized WITHIN each participant's 13 responses and then re-standardized BETWEEN all participants' responses. Formula = (value-MEAN)/STDEV.

Comment: The DV data set is the participants' responses (there are multiple other DVs). I perhaps should not be so concerned with the distribution. I am trying to meet assumptions of general linear models, but the Central Limit Theorem may cover.

Comment: The purpose of the WITHIN-BETWEEN approach was to account for the varying physiologies of the participants.  Between higher and lower levels of response.

Comment: Those operations make it impossible to carry out or interpret most comparisons.  You need to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Since each participant's physiology is different, some have higher scores than others.  The idea was to bring those differing physiologies to a baseline (first standardization), and then re-standardize among the entire dataset.  After the first standardization, the resulting full set (73 participants x 13 responses) had a MEAN = 0, but STD = 0.96, so the re-standardization brought the entire data set back to MEAN = 0 and STDEV = 1. There was not much difference between the standardization and re-standardization, and they correlate to 1.00.

Comment: Okay--but you continue to describe your *calculations.*  Because they are unusual and difficult to interpret, we have to wonder *why* you are carrying them out.  It would help us to know what your analytical objective is.

Comment: Sure thing.  This particular variable measures Heart Rate Variability from experiencing a series of 13 VR scenes to find out if some scenes cause a more relaxing (higher score) or stressful (lower score) response.  As each person has a different physiology some have naturally higher scores and some naturally lower scores, which could affect the ability to compare responses between subjects.  Therefore, I standardized the 13 responses of each participant to bring them to a baseline that could then be compared with other participants grouped into a single variable.

Comment: Instead of *standardizing* you should *control for* the physiology.  But again, you are describing your calculations without explaining what you are trying to learn.  Although some things can be learned about heart rate variability after this selective standardization process, many other things cannot, because essential information is lost in the standardization.

Comment: I am newbie to a lot of this, but by controlling for the physiology, would you mean establishing a separate control variable that accounts for the differences in the individual physiological response, such as an average of the 13 responses per participant?

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to learn what in each of these scenes may be affecting the emotional-mental responses of people and if any of these scenes may provide "restorative effects" in people.  These scenes are urban spaces.  I also measure skin response and pulse transit time, in addition to HRV.

Comment: Another key reason to standardize is that I have a series of DVs I'd like to compare with each other.  I am less concerned with "a one unit increase in this variable increases another variable by this much", and more concerned about which DVs are more affected, and which IVs are causing the most effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice!  I will check it out some more.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: "Restandardizing between" is not very clear, but it doesn't seem to make sense. Also, GLMs do not assume that any variable is normally distributed.  As an aside, a) You are using terms in non-standard ways and this is confusing a lot of us and b) Relying on Excel for data analysis flashes a red light, to me. Finally, I *think* you need some sort of multilevel model as you have repeated measures.  If this is important research I would consider hiring a consultant.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback.  I will carefully review each of your points and adjust as necessary.  You are correct, this is a repeated measures study design -- each participant exposed to the same 13 treatments (counterbalanced).  I attempted to standardize within each participant's 13 responses, but when combined into a data set with all participants, the resulting MEAN = 0, but STD = 0.96 and not 1.  I attempted to "re-standardize" BETWEEN the 73 sets of 13 responses to get MEAN = 0 and STD = 1.

Comment: I have edited the original question to hopefully make things more clear.

Comment: I won't vote to re-open this as I think the comments already include the essence of an answer. The short reply to _ Is this a valid way to standardize DV values?_ is to me: No. That throws away really important information if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 4):

This makes no sense to me.

Standardization in the sense of (value $-$ mean) / SD is just a linear scaling and will itself make no difference to how close any variable is to a normal reference distribution.

Something else is going on here.

The evidence needed is

1. The normal quantile plot for the original variable with the code you used to produce it.
2. Code showing how you standardized that variable.
3. The normal quantile plot for the standardized variable with the code you used to produce it.

The over-arching question is why do you think that this outcome variable needs to be normally distributed? What do you intend to do with it?

If you can post your data, that would be ideal. It could be for example that the data can be posted compactly as a table.

Comment: I have added more information and comments above to help with your response. Thank you!

Comment: This was an early answer, and the only one to date,  but mostly superseded by revisions and comments.  I won't try to revise or expand it, but it doesn't deserves any more upvotes, thanks!